# Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint, but the column does not have a unique constraint? postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, unique-constraint, python

By the way, I'm trying to automate the below using python, but I've isolated the SQL code and tried it by itself on pgAdmin III, and it still doesn't work.

So I have a table called **tableName**, and I use it to make a new table called **tableNameBuffer** using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableNameBuffer (LIKE tableName INCLUDING ALL)

TRUNCATE TABLE tableNameBuffer
```

In **tableName**, there is a column with a unique constraint, `short_form`, which also shows up in **tableNameBuffer** (this is good). However, when I try to mass insert data from **tableName** into **tableNameBuffer**`, I get the following error for a few select rows (that do have the same name):

> 'ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tableNameBuffer_name_idx"
>   DETAIL: Key (name)=(data) already exists.'

The name column does not have a unique constraint in either table, and I checked using:

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(oid) FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tableNameBuffer_key'
```

which gives the following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tableNameBuffer_key ON data.tableNameBuffer USING btree (short_form)
```

Just to clarify, there is no sequence or serial id (I don't think), and the problem only seems to be for the name column. All the other columns have duplicates (with the exception of **short_form** of course) but are inserting fine. I strongly believe the problem is not with the code, and since I am relatively new to SQL, maybe I'm overlooking something? If, however, I can't seem to find a solution, then maybe I'll look over the code extensively again.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just found an index made by the following command if that affects anything?:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tableName_index on tableName USING btree (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

The insert query is built using the code so it's a little hard to understand without posting all my code (and it's a lot) but basically:

```
INSERT ="INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES("%tableNameBuffer,",".join(headers))

INSERT += "%(" + ")s,%(".join(headers) + ")s );"

cur.execute( INSERT, data )
```

Where **headers** are the keys, **data** is the data to be inserted, and **cur** is the cursor to the database.

There is only the above index and the following constraint in tableName:

```
CONSTRAINT tableName_key PRIMARY KEY (short_form)
```

And OIDS is false if that makes a difference, and I don't think there is table inheritance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum, please tag your PostgreSQL version. And, if possible, add the actual tableName definition, index and constraints included.

Comment: Please show us the complete `insert into` statement you are using to copy the data

Comment: is there any table Inheritance??

Comment: Where does `data` come from in your code? But the unique key on `tableName (name)` certainly prevents duplicate values for `name` to be inserted. If that index exists on the original table then you might be be affected by a bug. For that to know we would need the **exact** Postgres version you are using - `select version();` will tell you. In older versions there were some collation related bugs with unique indexes (some caused by Postgres, some caused by operating system updates)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The postgres version is 9.5.17. Also this index exists on both tables. So is there any way I can remove the unique key but keep the index on the new table?

Comment: You can always drop the unique index. But if that was already present on the source table, I would assume the way you are building your `data` thingy generates duplicate values. Just to be sure you are not affected by some bug, you can verify that in the source: `select name from originaltable group by name having count(*) > 1`

Comment: Two possibilities: Your insert statement doesn't do the right thing (you should show the actual SQL string) or you have data corruption in the original table.

Comment: It turns out the unique index was exactly the problem. Thanks for all your guys' help!